# Matrix rank considering a real parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Assuming the linear system:

\begin{align}
& (1+\lambda)x+y+z=1 \\
& x+(1+\lambda)y+z=\lambda \\
& x+y+(1+\lambda)z=\lambda^2
\end{align}

for which I need to determine the rank of the matrix of the coefficients defined as:
\begin{equation}
A=\pmatrix{1+\lambda & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1+\lambda & 1 \\ 1 &1 &1+\lambda}
\end{equation}
, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Well, it is quite obvious that the rank is equal to $ since the rows/columns are linearly independent but I have to prove it. Therefore in an echelon attempt I have reached:

\begin{align}
A=\pmatrix{1 &1+\lambda &1 \\ 0 &1 &-1 \\ 0 &0 &-\left(\frac{\lambda+3}{\lambda+2} \right)}
\end{align}
for $\lambda \neq -3$.
Well, first of all I am not quite sure this is correct and secondly, is that enough? There is also a second question, which asks for which values of $\lambda$ the system has one solution, infinite and none respectively. 
Do I proceed with the determinant?

Lastly, can one direct me to a complete example of how to find the rank of a matrix with the use of minor determinants?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $A$ can be viewed as 
$$A = \lambda I - B,$$
where 
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix} = -\frac{1}{3}ee^T, \quad e = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\
1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ 
Hence $\lambda$ may be viewed as the eigenvalues of $B$. Therefore $\det(A) \neq 0$ if and only if $\lambda \notin \sigma(B)$, where $\sigma(B)$ denotes the set of eigenvalues of $B$. Clearly, $0 \in \sigma(B)$. On the other hand, since for any two matrices $X$ and $Y$, $XY$ and $YX$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues, we conclude that $B$ has a unique nonzero eigenvalue that is identical to the eigenvalue of $-\frac{1}{3}e^Te = -1$, which is $-1$.

In summary, if $\lambda \notin \{0, -1\}$, we have $\det(A) \neq 0$, thus $\text{rank}(A) = 3$.

If $\lambda = 0$, then clearly $\text{rank}(A) = 1$. If $\lambda = -1$, then $A$ has an obvious submatrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with nonzero determinant, we conclude $\text{rank}(A) = 2$.

Regarding to the number of solutions, it's convenient to take the point of view of range space (of columns) --- the system has (doesn't have)  solution if $b = (1, \lambda, \lambda^2)^T$ belongs (doesn't belong) to the space spanned by column vectors $a_1 = (1 + \lambda, 1, 1)^T, a_2 = (1, 1 + \lambda, 1)^T, a_3 = (1, 1, 1 + \lambda)^T$.

If $\lambda = 0$, then $b = (1, 0, 0)^T$, which can't be expressed as any linear combination of $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = (1, 1, 1)^T$. Therefore, the system has no solution.

If $\lambda = -1$, then $b = (1, -1, 1)^T$, $a_1 = (0, 1, 1), a_2 = (1, 0, 1)^T, a_3 = (1, 1, 0)^T$. It is easy to check that $u_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0)^T = (-1/2, 3/2, -1/2)^T$ is one solution of this system. Since $\text{rank}(A) = 2$, the dimension of the null space of $A$ equals to $3 - 2 = 1$, namely, the system $Au = 0$ has infinitely many solutions. Therefore, any vector with form $u_0 + u$, where $u \in \text{Ker}(A)$ is a solution to this system. Hence it has infinitely many solutions.

If $\lambda \notin \{0, -1\}$. Then the matrix $A$ is invertible, hence the system has a unique solution as $(x, y, z)^T = A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Thank you clearing things out :)

Answer (score 0):

What's obvious isn't always true.

When $\lambda = 0$, the  columns are identical, and the rank is $1$.

You might also want to look at $\lambda = -2, -3$.

Comment: oups! I don't know what was I thinking! :D So how should I proceed? Take cases? And what about the echelon form? Is that correct?

Comment: Try plugging $\lambda = 0$ into your echelon form: does it have rank 1? If not, then it's not correct. This one is simple and symmetric enough that computing the characteristic polynomial directly makes sense. It'll be cubic (ick), but you know that $\lambda$ is a factor, because $0$ is a root, so that leaves you with a quadratic. Should be simple.

Comment: You are right by $\lambda=0$ I get a rank 3. But why should I calculate the characteristic polynomial? I am a bit confused..

Comment: The eigenvalues of the all-ones matrix,  are the negatives of the roots of the characteristic polynomial of your matrix. If $\lambda$ is such a number, then your matrix will be singular (i.e., have less than full rank). But @Solitary's answer pretty much works through this for you, without sweating the char. poly., so that's an alternative approach.